# Adonis js with docker /app/server.js error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, adonis.js

I´ve been looking all over to find a solution to this, and i have the feeling it´s something small i´m missing but i just can´t get this working. I started with a adonis js v.5 app and then i want to dockerize it, but it keeps giving me the error below when i do docker-compose up --build:

```
lwdis-api         | Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
lwdis-api         |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
lwdis-api         |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
lwdis-api         |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
lwdis-api         |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
lwdis-api         |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
lwdis-api         |   requireStack: []
lwdis-api         | }
lwdis-api         | 
lwdis-api         | Node.js v17.5.0
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm i -g @adonisjs/cli && npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3333

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  lwdis_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "33101:3306"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - api-network
  lwdis_api:
    container_name: "${APP_NAME}-api"
    build: .
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    depends_on:
      - lwdis_db
    networks:
      - api-network

networks:
  api-network:
```

I started with [this](https://github.com/clio19/adonisJs-MySQL-docker-) package, and the problem was right at the begining, when i do the docker ps it shows the mysql container but not the api container, which i think it will be a problem since i have or want to add another modules etc. Then i deleted all containers and images related to it and this time i use the docker-compose up --build which shows me this error. I don´t have a server.js file but i have a server.ts file at the root of the app.

I was hopping someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The official cookbook article worked for me: https://v5-docs.adonisjs.com/cookbooks/dockerizing-adonis

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

API Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine3.9

RUN mkdir /srv/app && chown node:node /srv/app

RUN npm install -g @adonisjs/cli

USER node

WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --quiet

# TODO: Can remove once we have some dependencies in package.json.
RUN mkdir -p node_modules

COPY . .

RUN cp .env.example .env

#to run node.js script with sudo as we want to listen on port 80
USER root
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Mysql dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:10.4
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: "${SERVICE_PREFIX}-db"
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/mariadb/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ${DB_VOLUME_PATH}:/var/lib/mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    networks:
      - api-network
    restart: always
  api:
    container_name: "${SERVICE_PREFIX}-api"
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./docker/api/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../.:/srv/app
      - app_node_modules:/srv/app/node_modules
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0  # listen on all interfaces
      - SERVER_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:80" # matches actual listener message
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - api-network

networks:
  api-network:
    driver: "bridge"

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: "local"
  app_node_modules:
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @agilulfo, but i notess that you are using node 12.18, and adonis js v5 requires a t least node 14. I also saw that you are using mariadb adn in a different docker file...does it have to be two dockerfiles? couldn´t it be just one and mysql 8. Thanks for your time

Comment: Just update those things accordingly, it shouldn't change the base structure. I recommend a dockerfile for each service.